# GPS - NMEA GST position error to NED frame

Tags: gps, nmea

For my usecase I convert GPS position from [LLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Latitude_and_longitude) to [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Earth-centered,_Earth-fixed) to [NED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Local_tangent_plane) coordinate system. Works as expected. No issues.

Now I want to use the position 'standard deviation' delivered within the GPS NMEA 'GST' message. According this [side](https://www.trimble.com/oem_receiverhelp/v4.44/en/NMEA-0183messages_GST.html) it is defined as follows:

- Latitude 1 sigma error, in meters
- Longitude 1 sigma error, in meters
- Height 1 sigma error, in meters

Is my expectation correct that 'standard deviation' is expressed in ECEF coordinates ? Or what is the right way to convert 'standard deviation' into the NED frame ?

Comment: ECEF doesn't have latitude and longitude I assume std deviation is LLA, but so nearly equivalent of NED (with small variation, like normal std deviations). The semi-axis errors are (in my opinion) for ECEF.

Comment: So you mean it is valid to say: GST.lat_std = NED.north.std, GST.lon_std = NED.east.std, GST.height_std = NED.down.std ?

Comment: Yes. From the picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#/media/File:ECEF_ENU_Longitude_Latitude_relationships.svg you see it is the same. Height could be different but I do not remember how GPS calculates height (perpendicular vs toward center of Earth [different values on ellipsoid, but also not extremely different], but this you can correct easily).

Comment: Ok, so my fault was to calculate an 'intermediate ECEF standard deviation' which is rubbish. What do you mean with "...can correct easily..." ?

Comment: For most purposes, you may use the formula as above. If you need a very precise standard deviation of height, you may need to correct it. There are some formula on how to convert heights from perpendicular to center of earth (but I do not remember if LLA of GPS uses the first or the second definition). Usually irrelevant because other larger errors (geoid, which we do not have a precise model)

Comment: Ok I will ignore the height correction. Thanks a lot for your support !